# Yahoo Messenger IP range

Tags: blocking, tcpip, pidgin, yahoo-messenger

I use [PeerBlock](http://www.peerblock.com/) (former [PeerGuardian](http://www.peerblock.com/)) and, as a consequence, Yahoo Messenger (actually [Pidgin](http://www.pidgin.im/)) fails to connect every once in a while; PeerBlock reports the access being blocked because the destination IP is in one of the block lists.
Where can I get a list of all IP ranges belonging to Yahoo Messenger so I can configure an "allow" rule in PeerBlock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From
http://www.celticwolf.com/useful-information/faqs/26-pidgin-yahoo

> The domain name that is used to connect to Yahoo! servers is "scs.msg.yahoo.com".  This domain name is actually mapped to multiple servers.  Some of these servers have been upgraded, while others haven't.  As a result, you may see intermittent failures, or you may fail every time, while your neighbor logs in successfully.  It's effectively a roll of the dice.

The following addresses appear to work:

```
* cs101.msg.mud.yahoo.com
* 66.163.181.172
```

These are the IP addresses to which scs.msg.yahoo.com maps.  You can try one of them directly, but recent reports (on 6/19/2009) are that few, if any, are working.  Note also that there is no guarantee that the server at an address that works now will not be upgraded next.

```
* 76.13.15.36
* 76.13.15.37
* 68.180.217.6
* 68.180.217.7
* 68.180.217.8
* 68.180.217.9
* 68.180.217.10
* 68.180.217.11
* 68.180.217.12
* 68.180.217.13
* 68.180.217.14
* 76.13.15.29
* 76.13.15.30
* 76.13.15.31
* 76.13.15.32
* 76.13.15.33
* 76.13.15.34
* 76.13.15.35
```

You can verify this list yourself by running one of the following commands:

Windows: nslookup scs.msg.yahoo.com

Linux/Unix/OS X: dig +short scs.msg.yahoo.com

---

You may also want to try to whitelist;

- msg.edit.yahoo.com
- msg.mud.yahoo.com
- messenger.yahoo.com
- http.pager.yahoo.com

or if you can't whitelist domains, try;

- 216.136.175.143-145
- 216.136.225.83-48
- 216.136.225.12
- 216.136.226.209-210
- 216.136.227.166-167